# Function provided by professor does not output anything

Tags: python, image, function

My professor for my python class had this defined function in the lecture as an example of how to print out a string that would tell us if the first pixel of an image is more red, blue or green. My issue is that it does not output any value. This is word for word the code she put in the lecture slide but it does not do anything for me in Mu. What am I missing?

Below is the code:

```
def func3(img,x,y):
    pixel=img[x][y]
    r=pixel[0]
    g=pixel[1]
    b=pixel[2]
    if r<30 and g>230 and b<30:
        colourname='green'
    elif r>200 and g<30 and b<30:
        colourname='red'
    else:
        colourname='blue'
    return colourname
```

Comment: Yes, it does not output anything. You feed an image and x, y coordinates to this function and it returns a string with a color name. Check out how to use functions and welcome to programming BTW :-)

Comment: Did you call the function? Without calling it, no output is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have not understood functions properly.

Functions are a block of code which can be used multiple times.

functions run some code and return a result, like in your function, it is returning `colorname`

Now to get the output from a function, the first thing we have to do is call it.

So after defining the function;

```
def func3(img,x,y):
    pixel=img[x][y]
    r=pixel[0]
    g=pixel[1]
    b=pixel[2]
    if r<30 and g>230 and b<30:
        colourname='green'
    elif r>200 and g<30 and b<30:
        colourname='red'
    else:
        colourname='blue'
    return colourname

# now i will call the function by simply writing its name with parenthesis in which we have to provide the parameters required by the function

func3(some_img, x, y) # some_img, x, y are the values of the parameters on which the code will act.
```

Now if you want to print the result on the console, use the `print` function;

```
print(func3(some_img, x, y))
```

**Extra points to be noted as a beginner**

`return`  statement doesnot print anything on the console but is used to return a value from a function. What that means is, after the functions runs its code, at the end, it should be giving some value . Like in your example, you should be able to know at the end, which color it is. For that you return the `colorname`. `print`  function is for printing the things to the console.

Comment: Thank you for this in depth answer, it has been very helpful!

Comment: You can mark it as accepted and leave an upvote if it helped. Thanks